# Problem following guide - Configuring Raspberry pi as Router, Wifi and Ethernet Bridge - HowTo solve?

Tags: access-point, bridge, systemd-networkd

I'm trying to follow through Ingo's guide [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98511/configuring-raspberry-pi-as-router-wifi-and-ethernet-bridge/98551#98551)(Configuring Raspberry pi as Router, WiFi and Ethernet Bridge. One way or the other I can't seem to get it working though. I'm on Raspbian Buster.
I'm using a pi 3B v2, with a working usb network adapter.
After my first failure, I flashed a new microSD card and then (tried) followed the various posts:

- Use systemd-networkd for general networking [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108592/use-systemd-networkd-for-general-networking/108593#108593)
- Next: Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-access-point-the-easy-way/88234#88234). Creating the exact same four interface configuration files (02-br0.netdev / 08-wlan0.network / 12-br0_add-eth0.network / 16-br0_up.network), modified the wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service according the example.
  Up to the point where the guide says to reboot and check if the bridge works.

I have the pi connected to a monitor + keyboard.
The first thing I do after rebooting is run ifconfig to check network adapters and status.
This then shows only the lo with 127.0.0.1

I am at a loss on how to proceed.
Any help or tip will be hugely appreciated!

FYI
My internet provider hands out a range of 192.168.0.1/24
Purpose would be to connect eth1 to the internet switch.
Wlan0 + eth0 would then be bridged and serve out DHCP

Comment: While Ingo certainly has expertise with systemd-networkd his tutorials are difficult to follow (he uses Here Script, which obscure the file content and is running as root, without explaining how or why). [SystemdNetworkd]https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117843/8697 is a simpler tutorial. Either way you need to include the contents of your files for anyone to answer.

Comment: NOTE don't use `ifconfig` which is deprecated, use `ip a; ip r`

Comment: Extremely late to the show, but thanks anyway!
Any way to get mail notifications when a reply comes?